# SPF (include) permerror error

Tags: spf

Current TXT for domain.com is

```
host:@
value:v=spf1 include:mail.domain2.com ~all
```

Authentication Report from check-auth@verifier.port25.com

```
SPF check:          permerror
```

and http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html evalution is:

```
Results - PermError SPF Permanent Error: Two or more type TXT spf records found.
```

For Google is it ok:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

does it need implement some feature in my mail server mail.domain2.com for SPF?

Comment: You need to check your DNS contents - it looks like you have more than 1 SPF record. Show the output from `dig txt mail.example.com`. We can't check it for you because you did not post your domain.

Answer (score 2):

As far as you have only include statement you have to make all the same SPF checks for mail.domain2.com and as mentioned in comments show the SPF record for mail.domain2.com.

Most likely it's exactly what error says - you have several SPF TXT records for any given domain, either **mail.domain2.com** or **domain.com**, which is wrong. That typically happens when a domain already have some standard or previous SPF record and you need add more sending domains or IPs but mistakenly you added just an extra spf record.

The correct way to add more sending domains or IPs is to take the domain's existing SPF record, merge it with the new one in text editor, thoroughly check and put back replacing existing SPF record.

So for example if you already had a SPF for mail.domain2.com which says...

`'v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all'`

and you need to add lets say...

`'v=spf1 include:_spf.outlook.com ~all'`

then you have to merge them together as

`'v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:_spf.oulook.com ~all'`

and replace the existing one with that new merged one. So a domain's DNS must only return one `v=spf1` record when queried.